# Submit and Reset buttons using Javascript for dropdown list form

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to add 2 buttons to verify and reset dropdown list forms for a quiz using Javascript. My Verify button works but I need it also to show a window with the score. How to write a function to reset all of the forms to the first option?

```
  <script>
  function finalScore() {
    var i = 0;
    var select1 = document.getElementById("form1");
    var answer1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
           if(answer1 == "right"){
           i++;
     }

var select2 = document.getElementById("form2");
var answer2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer2 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select3 = document.getElementById("form3");
var answer3 = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer3 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select4 = document.getElementById("form4");
var answer4 = select4.options[select4.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer4 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select5 = document.getElementById("form5");
var answer5 = select5.options[select5.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer5 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select6 = document.getElementById("form6");
var answer6 = select6.options[select6.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer6 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select7 = document.getElementById("form7");
var answer7 = select7.options[select7.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer7 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select8 = document.getElementById("form8");
var answer8 = select8.options[select8.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer8 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select9 = document.getElementById("form9");
var answer9 = select9.options[select9.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer9 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select10 = document.getElementById("form10");
var answer10 = select10.options[select9.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer10 == "right"){
        i++;
    }
document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = i;
}

</script>




<body>
<div class="bloc1">
Select the word which does not belong to this food group from the selection list:
</div>
<div class="bloc2">
</br>
<form>
1. What food doesn’t belong to this food group?
</br>
<select id="form1">
  <option value="wrong">Banana</option>
  <option value="right">Beef</option>
  <option value="wrong">Peach</option>
  <option value="wrong">Nectarines</option>
  <option value="wrong">Plums</option>
  <option value="wrong">Tangerines</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
2. The food group in question 1 is:
</br>
<select id="form2">
  <option value="wrong">Meat, Poultry, Fish, Beans, Eggs and Nuts Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Fats, Oils and Sweets Group</option>
  <option value="right">Fruit Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Bread, Cereal, Rice and Pasta Group</option>
  <option value="right">Milk, Yogurt and Cheese Group</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
3. What food doesn’t belong to this food group?
</br>
<select id="form3">
  <option value="wrong">Chicken</option>
  <option value="wrong">Steak</option>
  <option value="wrong">Lamb</option>
  <option value="wrong">Crab</option>
  <option value="right">Kiwi</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
4. The food group in question 3 is:
</br>
<select id="form4">
  <option value="wrong">Bread, Cereal, Rice and Pasta Group</option>
  <option value="right">Meat, Poultry, Fish, Beans, Eggs and Nuts Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Vegetable Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Milk, Yogurt and Cheese Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Fats, Oils and Sweets Group</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
5. What food doesn’t belong to this food group?
</br>
<select id="form5">
  <option value="right">Apricot</option>
  <option value="wrong">Squash</option>
  <option value="wrong">Zucchini</option>
  <option value="wrong">Potato</option>
  <option value="wrong">Broccoli</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
6. The food group in question 5 is:
</br>
<select id="form6">
  <option value="wrong">Meat, Poultry, Fish, Beans, Eggs and Nuts Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Fruit Group</option>
  <option value="right">Vegetable Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Fats, Oils and Sweets Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Bread, Cereal, Rice and Pasta Group</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
7. What food doesn’t belong to this food group?
</br>
<select id="form7">
  <option value="wrong">Chocolate milk</option>
  <option value="wrong">Cream cheese</option>
  <option value="wrong">Ice cream</option>
  <option value="right">Salad dressing</option>
  <option value="wrong">Yogurt</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
8. The food group in question 7 is:
</br>
<select id="form8">
  <option value="wrong">Fruit Group</option>
  <option value="right">Dairy Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Vegetable Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Meat, Poultry, Fish, Beans, Eggs and Nuts Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Fats, Oils and Sweets Group</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
9. What food doesn’t belong to this food group?
</br>
<select id="form9">
  <option value="wrong">Cookies</option>
  <option value="wrong">Candy</option>
  <option value="right">Salad dressing</option>
  <option value="wrong">Cherries</option>
  <option value="wrong">Butter</option>
</select>
</form></br>

<form>
10. The food group in question 9 is:
</br>
<select id="form10">
  <option value="wrong">Dairy Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Vegetable Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Meat, Poultry, Fish, Beans, Eggs and Nuts Group</option>
  <option value="wrong">Bread, Cereal, Rice and Pasta Group</option>
  <option value="right">Fats, Oils and Sweets Group</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<div class="bloc3">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="finalScore()">
<input type="button" value="Reset all" onclick="clearall()">
</br></br>
Questions answered right:
<div id="scoreDisplay">score goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: Give them a class name and loop through each element of that class?

Comment: Here's a example: https://jsfiddle.net/cau7uzko/

Comment: You could use a class for all the answers too... meaning you wouldn't need to duplicate the `getElementsById()` or the if statement.

Comment: Maybe this will help you too...? https://jsfiddle.net/cau7uzko/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of a select element in JavaScript like this:

```
  document.getElementById("mySelectId").value = "myDefaultValue";
```

So, on your select whose id is "form10", for example, you can set the value like this in your clearall() function:

```
 function clearall() {
     document.getElementById("form10").value = "wrong";
 }
```

Repeat for the other "formX" elements and when you click the reset button, they will all revert to their default values.  To avoid repeating the code as above, you can do this in a loop from 1 to 10, but remember that you'll have to set form5 to "right", because that is the only select which has "right" as the first choice.